# Add SRI hash to existing CDN links

Tags: 9

I have a Drupal site where there are few CDN links. Iwas thinking of adding SRI hashes to those links.

How can I do that?

Every solution I tried requires to add a custom module, but I don't know how these things work.

Somehow, I managed to create a custom module which creates a Hello page. I just followed a tutorial. Can I add hashes in it?

#### sri.info.yml

```yaml
name: SRI Hash
type: module
description: 'SRI Hash'
package: custom
version: 8.x
core: 8.x
```

#### sri.routing.yml

```yaml
sri.scripthash:
  path: '/sri_hash'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\sri\Controller\SriController::scripthash'
    _title: 'SRI Hash'
    requirements: 
      _permission: 'access content'
```

#### SriController.php

```php
namespace Drupal\sri\Controller;

class SriController {
  /**
   * Returns a simple page.
   *
   * @return array
   *   A simple renderable array.
   */
  public function scripthash() {
    $element = array(
      '#markup' => 'This is a page !',
    );
    return $element;
  }
}
```

Is there another way to do it?

Comment: I think you are overcomplicating this :-) Usually external assets are defined in `*.libraries.yml` files of your theme/module, and you can add the SRI hash in the `attributes` section of the asset, [see example](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/adding-assets-css-js-to-a-drupal-theme-via-librariesyml#s-adding-attributes-to-script-elements)

Comment: Better example link: https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/adding-assets-css-js-to-a-drupal-theme-via-librariesyml#bootstrap

Comment: @Hudri thanks ... i have added the integrity hash, but after adding site breaks down,, shows message website encountered an error ! I have cleared the cache also, but it still shows the error, site works if i remove integrity hash.

Comment: We don’t know what you did because you haven’t shown us the code or the error message.